# From web database (PostgreSQL) to mobile (SQLite)

Tags: database, data, storage

My company employs people who add and edit records in a PostgreSQL database using a web interface. These updates then need to be compiled into a mobile app (Android, iOS) via SQLite and released as a new version every few months. We haven't quite gotten around to 'hot patching' the SQLite database; that is to say, downloading updates from the server instead of recompiling the app with new data downloaded during the build process.

I'm wondering what the typical process is here - how to get from server to client. My initial thought is to write a script to:

1. download the data (as JSON) that needs to be compiled into the app
2. use the SQLite library to construct the database and import the data
3. compress/encrypt the database
4. put the database in the correct asset folder for iOS and Android

It seems like a reasonable approach, but I'm wondering if there is a better way, or if there is some process that's more standard. Are there caveats to this approach?

And I know that I could expose this to clients via a REST API. That's basically what I'm doing for the 'downloading' aspect. However, that's not what the boss wants to do, so this is the way it has to be. I'm asking if my approach (downloading a JSON export, importing that data, etc.) is a decent approach, or if e.g. dumping through psql and doing some magic with that data) would be better for what I need to accomplish: getting PostgreSQL data from the web into a local SQLite database.

Comment: Why not expose the data using REST + JSON to the clients so they can update the SQLite database themselves?

Comment: @yorodm I would agree with that, but that's not what the boss wants to do :)

Comment: Why are you asking for a better way if you're locked into what the boss wants to do?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was asking if my approach for doing the task - getting data from PostgreSQL on the web into a local SQLite - was appropriate, or if there was a better way of doing it (e.g. through dumping the database through psql or something similar). I'm sorry if that wasn't very well-said.

Answer (score 1):

> However, that's not what the boss wants to do, so this is the way it has to be.

That's a dangerous path you are taking. Please put in metrics and logging. Make sure this is an improvement. I've rarley seen apps work faster because bosses made the technical choices.

Here's my (badly put) two cents :

> My initial thought is to write a script to:
>
> 1. download the data (as JSON) that needs to be compiled into the app
> 2. use the SQLite library to construct the database and import the data
> 3. compress/encrypt the database
> 4. put the database in the correct asset folder for iOS and Android

This isn't a bad idea but I'd recommend rather than encrypting whole database, try encrypting individual entries. There's less chance of corruption due to encryption. Make sure your decryption/encryption is secure and not exposed to attack vectors. Include versioning and fallbacks so when there's failure, you can be a bit more resilient.

Also, rather than writing a script in any language you fancy, write something in Java or C#, so when the time comes to move to the 'hot patching', these less work to do.